# How to access CM4 IO Board serially?

Tags: compute-module, compute-module-4

I have a Raspberry Pi CM4 IO Board and want to access it via serial console. Do I need to use external USB to TTL Rs232 Module Converter Serial Cable Adapter([USB to TTL Rs232](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B08HPSFFTT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) to connect serially? Or can I use micro USB cable and connect it to micro USB connector on IO board?

This is the pin diagram of CM4 IO Board

[image]

If I have to use USB to TTL Rs232 Module Converter, which pins of CM4 IO Board should be connected to serial adapter?